# Flutter - Multiple Parse Instances

Tags: flutter, dart, parse-platform, backend

Is there a way to use multiple parse instances in Flutter? Two backends should be addressed at the same time.

The following package was used:
[parse_server_sdk_flutter: ^3.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/parse_server_sdk_flutter)

```
    Parse instanceOne = await Parse().initialize(
    keyParseApplicationIdLogin, keyParseServerUrlLogin,
    clientKey: keyParseClientKeyLogin, debug: true);

Parse instanceTwo = await Parse().initialize(
    keyParseApplicationIdLoginDiGA, keyParseServerUrlLoginDiGA,
    clientKey: keyParseClientKeyLoginDiGA, debug: true);

//add User with mail adress on first server
ParseUser userWithMail =
    ParseUser.createUser(userName.text, passWord.text, eMail.text);

//another login should take place on the second server
```

Comment: I suspect you're more likely to get an answer by filing an issue against the package to ask its developers.

Comment: It is not posible. The SDK was designed to connect to a single instance of Parse Server at a time.

Comment: I honestly can't be bothered to really check if this works in depth, or I would do a writeup, but you may try simply: 

Parse parse1 = new Parse(); Parse parse2 = new Parse(); parse1.initialize(...); parse2.initialize(...);

When I try this, the objects are not equal and they pass health checks.

Comment: Alternatively, depending on what your actual need is here, you might just have the Flutter part speak to one Parse server, and have the two Parse servers communicate with each other.